# How to get only the favourite/starred contacts using ContactsContract

Tags: android

how can I get the favourite contacts (and only the favorite / starred) contacts?

I would like to not loop through the entire contacts list checking each contact if it is starred... is there some query I can use to return only favourite/starred contacts?

thanks

Comment: Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351626/getting-favourites-contacts-in-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, "starred=?",
            new String[] {"1"}, null);
```

where the `starred=?` will be your filter and `"1"` would suggest to pick up only favorites.

Comment: Instead of the hardcoded string `"starred"`, you should consider using [`ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.html#STARRED).