# Is there any way to fetch SPEED DIAL contacts list in android lollipop devices

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

As we know that android lollipop has three tabs in dialer contact screen SPEED DIAL, RECENTS and CONTACTS. My question is that SPEED DIAL list shows speed dial contacts list. I want to fetch this SPEED DIAL contact list in my application. Please help me to solve this problem.

Note:-
* Favourites contacts list is a different thing. I do not want to fetch Favourites contacts list. I want to fetch SPEED DIAL list no matter contact is favourite or not. Please help me.

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: I have write code to fetch contacts list. So I have written code for it. I did not write code for fetch SPEED DIAL list.

Comment: Please have a look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18071357/1793718) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351626/getting-favourites-contacts-in-android) post

Comment: Ok, I am trying using this.

Comment: It's not working. It shows favourites contact or starred contact. It does not shows SPEED DIAL list.

Comment: Please give me answer! I also need this. Please save me!

Comment: Any solution to this problem? Please post your answers.