# i have to block status bar and home navigation bar. i used below code to block it

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

```
 private void hideSystemUI() {

 View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

 int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;

  decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
   }
```

and also:

```
@Override

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{

 super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

  View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

  decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener( 
        newView.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

         @Override

         public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int i) {

            if (i == View.VISIBLE){
                hideSystemUI();
            }
            else {
                hideSystemUI();
            }
        }
    });
```

wrote the hidesystemUI() code in onCreate() and onResume() also, including with 
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(). So i have to block it. Once i swipe at the top, it is coming and going back ( like a blink). But i have to block it. Once we swipe at the top it should not appear. help me out of this.

Comment: check this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969086/how-to-disable-status-bar-click-and-pull-down-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want it to blink, you may delay hiding. For example, you can give it a 2 seconds delay by `Handler.postDelayed()`.

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    final int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
    }, 2000); //2 seconds delay
}
```

If you are always calling this on the main thread, you can simply call `new Handler()` to return a Handler on the main thread. Otherwise, you will need to call `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`.

Comment: Sorry Siu, this is not the exact solution i'm looking for. But i understood that blocking the system UI permanently is not possible and that is possible only for System apps. So i found another way for that--Thank you.

Comment: No problem! I thought you just don't like it blinking. Glad you find the solution! :)

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve name, mobile number and photo from favourite contacts.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) is the official tutorial on how to get contacts. 
You may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18892586/3061187) for getting only favourite contacts. Notice the query uses ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED=1 . You may check if the contact has phone number by adding ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER into the query's projection field. You can then get phone numbers by the ID as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11219123/3061187).

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108804/how-to-retrieve-name-mobile-number-and-display-photo-from-favourite-starred-con?noredirect=1#comment83192768_48108804)      ... once check the link plz, my updated code and question.

Comment: Had a quick look. Not sure why you using GROUP_PROJECTION. I guess if what you need are favourited contacts' phone number, name, photo, the projection should be `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI`. Check out [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) to see what you can use. And of course, keep the "starred=1" selection criteria.

Comment: Thanks a lot Siu... Works perfect.. you saved my day.. :)